# Kafka connect oracle-cdc autogenerates schemas for every topic with the same name "ConnectDefault". Can it be customized per topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry, debezium, change-data-capture

I'm using Kafka Connect with the oracle cdc (https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/oracle-cdc/current/overview.html) source connector to do CDC on some database tables. It creates a topic per table and autogenerates an Avro schema form each one. The problem is all schemas have the same namespace and name:

```
  "name": "ConnectDefault",
  "namespace": "io.confluent.connect.avro",
  "type": "record"
```

Can this be customized?

I've already tried setting different configuration properties in the connector config but none of the fixed the problem:

```
"value.converter.schema.name.strategy": "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy",

"value.converter.schema.registry.subject": "my.namespace.myname",

"transforms":"AddNamespace",
"transforms.AddNamespace.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata$Value", 
"transforms.AddNamespace.timestamp.record.namespace":"example",
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct property name for changing the subject is `value.converter.` + **`value.schema.name.strategy`** (you are missing the `value` part)

`schema.registry.subject` is not a valid config; use the transform for that.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/index.html#configuration-details

But that will not change the namespace. For that, `timestamp.record.namespace` is not the correct property, either. It is `schema.name`

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/setschemametadata.html#properties

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer suggests using a transform. For this particular component you have to consider this:

> The SMTs that alter schema are restricted to the table topics using
> predicates as demonstrated in the SMT Examples documentation.

Using predicates and transform the code looks like this:

```
    "predicates": "idDepartment",

    "predicates.idDepartment.pattern": "depcdc",
    "predicates.idDepartment.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates.TopicNameMatches",

    "transforms": "SetSchemaDepKey, SetSchemaDepValue",

    "transforms.SetSchemaDepKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata$Key",
    "transforms.SetSchemaDepKey.schema.name": "com.codependent.DepKey",
    "transforms.SetSchemaDepKey.predicate": "idDepartment",

    "transforms.SetSchemaDepValue.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata$Value",
    "transforms.SetSchemaDepValue.schema.name": "com.codependent.DepValue",
    "transforms.SetSchemaDepValue.predicate": "idDepartment",
```